# would windows 7 be blocking filezilla from connecting to FTP?

Tags: windows-7, filezilla

would windows 7 be blocking filezilla from connecting to FTP by default?

Answer (score 1):

could be the firewall, to to control panel, turn it off, then try again
if that does it, you'll have to turn the firewall on the edit it to let filezilla through

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 or your router might be blocking ports necessary to get the directory listing depending on the setup of the FTP server you are trying to connect to but by default Windows 7 isn't blocking outgoing connections.

Are you able to login but not see a file list or are you not able to login at all (see the log to be sure)?

Answer (score -1):

Go the this path "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Firewall\Allowed Programs"
(without quotes) and click on change setting, click on  "add another program" now from add program window browse for filezilla server ( file zilla interface is already listed ) and allow the program as you wish ( ie. for domain, private network and/or public network

-Mohammad Mohsinul Malik